# manipulating lists

Tags: c#

I have written a code to manipulate the contents of a time series data and output into a newly created matrix. This is to enable me construct the phase space for the time series data.

The list is one-dimensional of length=N called "noise".

I want to create a MxN matrix where `m = N -5*tdelay1` and `n = 6`. When the code complies it displays an error:

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.

The code is below:

```
float[,] phaseSpace6 = new float[(length-5*tdelay1-1), m];
for (int i = 0; i < (length-5* tdelay1-1); i++)
{
    int col1 = i + tdelay1;
    int col2 = i + 2 * tdelay1;
    int col3 = i + 3 * tdelay1;
    int col4 = i + 4 * tdelay1;
    int col5 = i + 5 * tdelay1;
    phaseSpace6[i, 1] = noise[i];
    phaseSpace6[i, 2] = noise[col1];
    phaseSpace6[i, 3] = noise[col2];
    phaseSpace6[i, 4] = noise[col3];
    phaseSpace6[i, 5] = noise[col4];
    phaseSpace6[i, 6] = noise[col5];
}
```

I am not sure why this is happening, as someone new to programming. I will be grateful if some experienced person could help me out.

Comment: Why don't you just use `phaseSpace6.GetLength(0)` and `phaseSpace6.GetLength(1)`? I have to downvote this question because of the lack of effort that went into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the N dimension of your MxN array is 6 as stated then `[i, 6]` is going to be out of bounds. Numbering for arrays starts at 0 not 1.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the result of

```
int col5 = i + 5 * tdelay1
```

is bigger than the noise dimension

Please show the test values used for `tdelay1`, and I assume that `length` is the dimension of `noise`? (N==length)

And, remember, the index of the arrays starts from zero to lenght-1. (As @Mykroft said in its answer)